# glmer and odds ratios

Tags: regression

Is there a way to calculate odds ratios for a glmer model?

My model is defined as follows:

```
results_reduced <- glmer(R0A1 ~ MPHW_Perc + AG_Perc + Shrub_Perc + Dist_PrimaryRoads 
                         + Dist_SecondaryRoads + (1 | ID), data = secondorder_st,
                         family = binomial)
```

I would like to calculate odds ratios for this model with associated confidence intervals; however, the following syntax that I would use in GLM continues to run without stopping:

```
#odds ratios and 95% CI
exp(cbind(OR = coef(results_reduced), confint(results_reduced)))
```

Therefore, I assume that the random effect is causing some hang-up issue. Is there a way to output the odds ratio for a mixed-effects model?

Answer (score 2):

The random effects probably aren't the problem. 1st, `coef(glmm_model)` pulls up a list of your fixed and random effects.  You want `fixef(glmm_model)`. 2nd.How large is your dataset?  Calculating confidence intervals for glmm models takes time (sometimes minutes), so you might just not be waiting long enough.  3rd, For `glmer` the default way to calculate confidence intervals is "`profile`."  Depending on your data it will often throw warnings, which might not cooperate when nested in your calls to `cbind` and `exp`.  You could try `confint(..., method ="Wald")`,  or doing things piece by piece.

Comment: @N Brouwer...I ran the following R code to output the odds ratios with no luck: exp(cbind(OR = fixef(results_reduced), confint(results_reduced))). I then ran the code separately: exp(fixef(results_reduced)) and exp(confint(results_reduced,method="Wald")) and got the estimates for both the OR and confidence interval. Not sure why the full code didn't work but at least I got the responses that I needed. Thanks again!